# IE breaking date submission form

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

I've been trying to fix a problem with a form that someone before me wrote and for some reason when someone enters a date (e.g. 01/02/2014) IE (all versions) cuts off the last digit so the year reads 01/02/201.

Any Idea what can be causing this?

```
<td colspan="6">Dates Worked:&nbsp;&nbsp;From&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="workdatesfrom1" 

         style="width:80px" maxlength="10" 

         value="<?php 
                    if($workdatesfrom1<>'01/01/1900') {
                       print($workdatesfrom1);
                    } 
               ?>"

         maxlength="10" id="workdatesfrom1" 

         onFocus="javascript:vDateType='1'"

         onKeyDown="DateFormat(this,this.value,event,false,'1')"

         onBlur="DateFormat(this,this.value,event,true,'1')"

         OnKeyUp="textCounter(
                      document.getElementById('app2').workdatesfrom1,
                      document.getElementById('app2').workdatesto1,
                      10
                 )" 
    />
</td>
```

JS:

```
function textCounter(field, tabfield, maxlength) {
    if (field.value.length == maxlength) // get to max then tab
    tabfield.focus();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make the code readable?

Comment: Sorry about that, is this better?

Comment: I tried to edit the code for you to make it better, but your style of putting fairly complex PHP and JS expressions inside HTML entities makes your code very hard to read. Try to separate logic from layout as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's not my code it is something the guy before me wrote and I've been tasked with fixing it (I don't know much myself). I'll give it another shot but failing that I can show it in notepad++ with syntax highlighted via a screenshot or something if that would be better. I just can't get the code to show properly on here.

Comment: What is the code for the functions DateFormat and textcounter?

Comment: From what I can tell, it's something that is happening in the functions DateFormat and or textCounter. Looking at the code you provided, it should work if those two functions are correct.

Comment: We really need to see your `DateFormat` -- I'm willing to guess that is where the problem is.  Javascripot has both `getYear` and `getFullYear`.  This sounds like the code is using the broken `getYear` method.  Try usign `getFullYear` instead.

Comment: Rather than try to shoehorn the whole thing into a comment I'm just going to poste the entire page sans database/url info. Here's the page: [link]http://pastebin.com/K2cgZttt

Comment: Also thank you for editing my original post to make sense! The guy that wrote this stuff was not a fan of readable...anything, really.

Comment: @user3308223 I couldnt find the `DateFormat` function on the pastebin link. It might be in any of the linked JS files, can you find it and post it here? I have edited the question and added the `textCounter` function.

Comment: I think I've found it in the dFilter.js file. [link]http://pastebin.com/ET5CSJ2x

Comment: I think I might have found the issue but I'm unsure how to fix it; one of the 'else' fields has a note "//If the value is not in the string return the string minus the last key entered" which is exactly what it's doing in IE. [link]http://pastebin.com/9TvJKpFW

Comment: Just looking at that DateFormat function gives me nightmares. You are better of using a library.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it! I deleted the 'else' statement that says "//If the value is not in the string return the string minus the last key entered" and it is working properly. Thanks everyone for helping me find the right place to look, and hopefully I can replace this horrible form in the next couple of months with one that wasn't written (badly) in 2004.